# How to rotate pages from a PDF in swift macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, pdf

I have a PDF document and I want to rotate all it's pages with 90 degrees. I found a solution [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html) but I can't make it work. The resoult PDF is empty. Any help would be great.

Here is my code:

```
guard let getCGPDFPage = pdfReference!.page(at: index) else {
                        NSLog("Error occurred in creating page")
                        return
                    }

                    page = getCGPDFPage
                    mediaBox = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)

                    // Get rotation angle and convert from degrees to radians:
                    let angle = CGFloat(page.rotationAngle) * CGFloat.pi / 180
                    // Apply rotation transform to media box:
                    var rotatedBox = mediaBox.applying(CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle))

                    let m = page.getDrawingTransform(.mediaBox, rect: rotatedBox, rotate: 90, preserveAspectRatio: true)

                    writeContext?.concatenate(m)
                    writeContext?.clip(to: page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox))
                    writeContext?.beginPage(mediaBox: &rotatedBox)
                    writeContext?.drawPDFPage(page)
                    writeContext?.endPage()
```

Comment: would it be possible to edit your question to show the code you're using in your app to do the transform? when you say you can't make it work, what's not working?  No pages rotate?  You're getting errors?

Comment: The page dimensions are ok, but pages are blank

Comment: thanks for adding that code.  What's `writeContext`?  What does `getCGPDFPage`?

Comment: writeContext is the CGContext to draw in and getCGPDFPage is a CGPDFPage object and it's the current page that we want to rotate

Comment: This isn't a good topic.  Where are 'page' and 'mediaBox' defined?

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to rotate the page of a PDF file than by using CoreGraphics to transform each page's context.

Use PDFKit's `PDFPage` object, which contains a property for the page's rotation. You can set this to 90, 180, 270 or 0 degrees.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfpage/1503443-rotation

Note that `CGPDFPage` and `CGPDFDocument` are different from `PDFPage` and `PDFDocument`.